# Button doesnt work because clashed with other button odoo 10

Tags: javascript, odoo-10, qweb

i have made a button that can send data to ajax server but another button doesnt work and it looks like my button are clashed because of the javascript, here is the javascript :

```
odoo.define('vit_product_barcode.print_button', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var form_widget = require('web.form_widgets');
    var core = require('web.core');
    var _t = core._t;
    var QWeb = core.qweb;

    form_widget.WidgetButton.include({
        on_click: function() {
             if(this.node.attrs.custom === "print"){
                console.log("trigered");
                var view = this.getParent();

            var printer_data = view.datarecord.printer_data;
            if (!printer_data){
                alert('No data to print. Please click Update Printer Data');
                return;
            }

            console.log(printer_data);
            //urlencode()//jsonp: > jika tidak json.stringify
            $.ajax("http://localhost/pproxy/print.php", {
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                jsonrpc: "2.0",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "printer_data" : printer_data
                    }),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(data) {},
            });

         }
        this._super();
    },
});
```

so the problem is when i made the last "this._super()" as an executeable code, my button that can send data to ajax wont work and get error like this:

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 675, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 331, in _call_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 119, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 324, in checked_call
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 933, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
TypeError: load() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

and when i made it as a comment (unexcuteable) the button that can send data to ajax wont work, but the other button will work. here are the buttons:

```
  <header>
     <button string="Get Data" type="object" name="action_print"/>
     <button type="action" string="Direct Print" icon="fa-print" custom="print"/>
  </header>
```

the button that can send data to ajax is the one with "Direct Print" string, the other button is the one with "Get Data" string.

so what should i do to solve this problem and my button wont clash anymore, ill be grateful if anyone here can help me

Comment: Did you add your XML-Files to the openerp.py?

Comment: yes i did, and the qweb too